# Help with RPC call on Polygon Network

Tags: web3j, java

I've developed an app to generate random wallet addresses and PvtK using a phrase seed file.

[image]

My code will check on a list of RPC addresses to verify if some wallet have some balance. The strange is what you can see in the image: The Polygon RPC is giving me a LOT of wallets with some balances. It makes me VERY happy at first, but when I go to https://polygonscan.com/ to check if this is true, the wallet address have no money.

I know it is very very very almost impossible (seriously) to create a valid address, but I'm doing nothing at home. Will spend some time with this. So please do not enter in this question. I'm doing this for fun.

This is how I check the address for the balance:

```
Web3j network = Web3j.build(new HttpService( "https://polygon-rpc.com" ) )
EthGetBalance ethGetBalance = network.ethGetBalance(address, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).send();
BigDecimal res = Convert.fromWei( ethGetBalance.getBalance().toString() , Unit.ETHER );
```

So, I believe this is some kind of error or even a bug in RPC endpoint, because there is no way that I can generate one single wallet address already in use in all of my life. Create more than 300 in a hour is a probability that I can even describe.

Well.. my question is: Can someone tell me what is really happening?

Some address:

```
0x0f6b61552275bda727f411a64a114ad1cc9d5fd5  0.034395746887658928    MATIC Polygon   
0x267f743ffed375a93bbfdc39171493bd45aad3f0  0.013375465755175522    MATIC Polygon   
0x19e46e09cb8ddf15e571d2973be7a976f53fbc69  1.901357336980710148    MATIC Polygon   
0x9984170dad63029b588632ed1b7b4842a524bd22  1.536544406612028835    MATIC Polygon   
0x2cf11a4974f5f0f34ca6f6a401f40a5b4a7073ef  0.000102122808648000    MATIC Polygon   
0xf7cdae93007f38668c30d11c587f122da24e03da  3.419920088559694534    MATIC Polygon   
0x1067122f9cfcf9cb39ed0dc55a2874f6945febc4  0.207568345729287071    MATIC Polygon   
0x209a97d7ffea76a52f3b9eae3ade7a2de0523086  71.972479906496035788   MATIC Polygon   
0x203c9cf56367977dbc6e985523fe18f0f097005d  42.27921785761202989    MATIC Polygon   
0xdc890c4233eb09a762fe77b4e9252243d771adeb  10.045603518538710098   MATIC Polygon   
0xeb9a6d200562b31c8a7aceb96a41b1d553b23303  0.0001021228086480000   MATIC Polygon
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Web3js got me accurate results, this may be an issue with the Web3j library.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

const web3 = new Web3("https://polygon-rpc.com");

web3.eth.getBalance("0x0f6b61552275bda727f411a64a114ad1cc9d5fd5").then(console.log);
```

Additionally, in the future if you want to eliminate the possibility of a faulty RPC, you can always grab something more robust for free from a provider like Chainstack.